# kill gnu parallel inside a bash function

Tags: bash, kill, gnu-parallel

I am using gnu parallel in a subshell function, e.g.,

```
func()(
    parallel --will-cite sleep ::: 60
)
```

upon sending `SIGTERM` to the function I want parallel to be killed too. But I get

```
$ func &
[1] 13255
$ pgrep -P 13255 # child of func -> the subshell
13256
$ pgrep -P 13256 # child of the subshell -> gnu parallel
13257
$ kill -TERM -- -13255 # terminating the process group
parallel: SIGTERM received. No new jobs will be started.
parallel: Waiting for these 1 jobs to finish. Send SIGTERM again to stop now.
parallel: sleep 60
$ kill -TERM -- -13255 # sending a second SIGTERM
bash: kill: (-18093) - No such process
```

so I cannot kill parallel without first tracking its process id. I tried to put a trap inside the function

```
func()(
    trap "pkill -P $$; pkill -P $$; exit" TERM
    parallel --will-cite sleep ::: 60
)
```

where `pkill -P $$` should kill all children, but checking `ps $pid_of_parallel` revealed, parallel keeps running after the first termination signal.

My goal is to write the function such that `funct &; kill $!` will terminate it and all children immediately. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the newest version of GNU parallel includes this now. From the GNU parallel development list:

> On Sun, Mar 10, 2019 at 8:29 PM Ole Tange  wrote:
>
> To stop GNU Parallel today you need to send TERM to make it stop
>   starting new jobs followed by another TERM to kill the running jobs.
>
> I am considering changing that to send HUP to stop starting new jobs
>   and TERM to kill running jobs.
>
> This will make it easier to kill GNU Parallel:
>
> $ bash -c 'parallel -j1 sleep ::: 111 222' &
>
> This would then kill the process group with bash and parallel
>
> $ kill -TERM -$!
>
> It will make it incompatible with previous versions.
>
> So the newest version includes this. Please, please, please see if you
>   can break that.
>
> Can you show an example where the new behavior is worse than the old?
>
> /Ole